# What does the "_" means before the directory in Angular

Tags: angular

I am a starter in Angular and I was following a tutorial to learn about authentication. During this tutorial, I saw that some directories start with an underscore others without. Could someone explain to me the reason?

[image]

Comment: I think it's one of the ways to put those directories above others

Comment: Just the authors preference. It has no significance in angular itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nomenclature is not Angular specific. It's a way to have the directories show at the top of the directory tree - a good method to keep frequently accessed directories from floating down.